# Why is running on android device using adb recommended?

Tags: react-native

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) provides 2 methods on how to connect to development server: using adb reverse and via wifi. It also says the former is recommended.

Is there a reason why (aside from maybe being easier to setup)? Just curious if there's any disadvantage to connecting via wifi, which I prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no disadvantage to using WiFi. Go for it. I think they recommended only because it's easier to set up, so they get less questions about it.